# Pandas plot bar groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame like the following:

```
year  crime   count
2005  A        1
2009  A        4
      D        1
2012  B        6
2014  C        2
      D        1
2017  A        3
      B        3
```

And I would like to plot a bar graph like this:
[image]

Where the bins are the years (2005, 2009, 2012, 2014, 2017) and each bin shows a bar for the available 'crime' (A, B , C, D).

Answer (score 0):

If input data are `DataFrame with MultiIndex` select column `count` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df['count'].unstack().plot.bar()
```